# Google Chrome Plugin: How to get domain from URL (tab.url)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Using the Google Chrome API's [`tab.url` value](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab), what is the best method to get just the domain from the entire value?

In JavaScript I would use `window.location.protocol` & `window.location.hostname`. For example something like this:

```
var domain = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
```

But that gets the extension domain and not the tab so cannot use that method.  So with a function similar to the one below... How would I strip just the domain from the `tab.url` value?

```
function show_alert() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        var currentURL = tab.url;
        alert(currentURL);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 61):

Since this question was originally answered, a better solution has appeared.

Most modern browsers now support use of the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL), which provides access to `href`, `hostname`, `path` and all standard ways of splitting up a URL.

To get the domain, you could do the following:

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
  var tab = tabs[0];
  var url = new URL(tab.url)
  var domain = url.hostname
  // `domain` now has a value like 'example.com'
})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Just say no to crazy regexes! :-)

Comment: @ross-zurowski can you please check out my post about migrating from the depreciated `getSelected` method and maybe using `getCurrent` over `query`?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029859/8023318

Comment: @kinghat thanks for the ping. I just updated this answer to use the new `query` API rather than the old `getSelected` one.

Comment: thanks @RossZurowski! were you able to get `getCurrent` working in any fashion?

Comment: @kinghat, I haven't tried. According to the [Chrome release notes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new#16), using `query({ active: true })` is the new recommended approach for getting the current tab — I think because `getCurrent` returns `undefined` for [background pages of extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent).

Comment: For some reason I'm getting `active: true
audible: false
autoDiscardable: true
discarded: false
height: 916
highlighted: true` but not the url...

Comment: @MichalStefanow, I just tested this code and it continues to work for me. You're getting the callback with an object but it doesn't have a `url` property? If that's the case, I'd wonder if might be related to extension permissions…

Comment: I think it is solved now. Maybe I didn't properly reload the extension, maybe something else.

Comment: Getting an error when using this code: `Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` at line 3. Update: The extension didn't have access to the site, I had to manually give it access. Fixed now!

Answer (score 17):

First of all, domains don't include a protocol. I have created a regular expression for your problem. To get the hostname (you'd want to do this as IP addresses are not domains) of a URI, use the the following:

```
var domain = uri.match(/^[\w-]+:\/{2,}\[?([\w\.:-]+)\]?(?::[0-9]*)?/)[1];
// Given uri = "http://www.google.com/", domain == "www.google.com"
```

If you want the origin (protocol + host (not hostname, there's a difference) + optional port) instead of the domain, use [the following](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/574682):

```
var origin = uri.match(/^[\w-]+:\/{2,}\[?[\w\.:-]+\]?(?::[0-9]*)?/)[0];
// Given uri = "http://www.google.com/", origin == "http://www.google.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chrome.tabs.query(
  {
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  },
  ([currentTab]) => {
    const url = new URL(currentTab.url);
    const domain = url.hostname;
    console.log(domain);
  }
);
```

combination of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37486863/8023318 but not using the depreciated `getSelected` and https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755190/8023318. would like to see if this can be done via `getCurrent`.