# How can I get the current tab URL for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I know there are many similar questions on SO, but I cannot seem to get it working.

I am trying to get the URL of the current tab from my Chrome extension.  Hoewever, the alert(tab.url) returns "Undefined".  I have added the "tabs" to my permissions in the manifest.json.  Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tab = tab.id;
        tabUrl = tab.url;

        alert(tab.url);
    });

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: This method is deprecated. [take a look!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18437759/2396846)

Comment: is there any way to avoid a query/poll, and instead listen for a click, to determine the active tab?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
tab = tab.id;
```

It should be something like:

```
var tabId = tab.id;
```

Comment: You changed the variable tab by mistake... careful next time :)

Comment: getSelected is deprecated. Please use tabs.query {active: true}
[tabs#method-getSelected](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected)

Comment: Hi i need **focused tab info**.. if I have more than 5 tab in browser, if click (focused ) tab 1 then "action trigger" or tab 2/3/4/5.. every time a tab focused then it should trigger.so what can i do?

Answer (score 163):

Just an FYI for people from Google:

The method OP uses is deprecated. To get the tab the user is viewing and only in the window they are viewing use this:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
  // since only one tab should be active and in the current window at once
  // the return variable should only have one entry
  var activeTab = tabs[0];
  var activeTabId = activeTab.id; // or do whatever you need
});
```

Comment: This should be chosen now as the old way will not work for multiple reasons.

Comment: Discovered that if you have two Chrome windows side-by-side with the extension open in one, and you focused the other window before using the extension to make an http request, the request will be made in the context of the other window and host permissions for that window will be required. Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 15):

In manifest.json:

```json
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

In JavaScript:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
    var tab = tabs[0];
    console.log(tab.url);
    alert(tab.url);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
    var tab = tabs[0];
    console.log(tab.url);
    alert(tab.url);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but didnt work.

Answer (score 6):

With a little help of ES6, you can easily write nicer code :)

```
chrome.tabs.query({
  active: true,
  currentWindow: true
}, ([currentTab]) => {
  console.log(currentTab.id);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The newest versions indicates it must be like this

```js
async function getCurrentTab() {
  let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
  return tab;
}
```

And you must **add to your manifest.json this**

```json
"permissions: [
    "tabs"
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember to add this to your manifest.json file

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone using [Web Extension Polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) like me, for cross browser support.

```js
// using async function
const [currentTab] = await browser.tabs.query({
  active: true,
  currentWindow: true,
});

console.log({ id: currentTab.id, url: currentTab.url });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was missing the "tabs" permission as per [Kartik Kkartin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45386252/2284676) answer

Rest of the code in my background script

```
chrome?.tabs?.onUpdated?.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
    console.log('tabId', tabId, 'changeInfo', changeInfo, 'tab', tab)
  }
})
```

That will log the tab information, including the url in the `tab.url` when loading a tab