# Get data from background script into popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the current tab url from background.js and render it onto the popup.html. How can I do the same? I am using the Vuejs framework to create a plugin.

I tried sending the data as a message from background.js to popup. But the onClicked event does not allow it to be run on the popup.

I expect to have the url of the current open tab in the popup plugin, with which I intend to do other things.

Comment: you can use vanilla JS code: window.location.href

Comment: To get current tab use chrome.tabs.query as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17826527).

Comment: I want to get the data from my background.js into the vuex store.

Comment: And then from my vuex store, render that url into my popup.html. The Vue cli store does not store anything when used as a plugin, so I am very confused on the code structure for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the data to `chrome.storage.local` right in the backgroundt and detect this fact in your popup using `chrome.storage.onChanged` event.

Comment: @MohitKamal Did you try it?

Comment: Is there a way I can incorporate the vue store into the chrome extension, or do I explicitly need to user chrome.storage api only?

My basic Vuejs app uses a basic store which I want to use in the chrome extension

Comment: Do you want to create 'chrome extension'?

Comment: Yes. I am creating a chrome plugin using Vuejs where I want to get the url of the current tab, and in the popup.html, there is a button which does an api call using that url.

Comment: Did you get the current tab and save in state in vue?

Comment: Where do you want to save date about current tab page?

Comment: I am sorry for my novice understanding, as I am fairly new to chrome extension development. I am getting the current tab url from chrome.tabs.query from background.js.

Now I want to save this url in my vuejs popup.

I hope you are getting me

Comment: I would do as I did in response. This is my idea

Comment: One more question. Can I get the chrome.storage data from background.js directly into my vuejs store via actions or mutations?

Comment: You can use `chrome.storage.local.get` and assign to variable. `const d = chrome.storage.local.get`. variable `d` save to state