# How to know if the active tab is correct for chrome extension (manifest 3)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am a beginner in developing Chrome Extensions. I am currently working on an extension. Consider an extension, which only works on Instagram pages (.com, .in, ... and so on). Now there are two conditions:

1. If it is an Instagram page, the `popup.html` says 'YES' and change some contents of DOM.
2. If it is not an Instagram page, the `popup.html` says 'NO' and there is no change in DOM.

```
    {
        "name": "Extension",
        "description": "Description goes here",
        "version": "1.0",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "permissions": ["tabs"],
        "content-scripts": { // DO SOMETHING HERE
        }
    }
```

I am using Manifest Version 3. Can I know the way I can check if the domain of the active tab is instagram, and if it is so, then where/how should I mention the source of the js file to be executed.

Comment: You have the information you need in the documentation for [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#functionality) and [tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab).

Comment: It depends on what the actual functionality is. Anyway, to change the web page you need a content script where you specify `matches` for instagram. The popup is a separate thing, which is opened on click. In the popup you can [get the active tab's url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132018/) and change the popup's element's text accordingly. P.S. you have a typo: `content-scripts` should be spelled with `_`.